# React Print Automatically

Tags: reactjs, printing

I'm looking at printing a form from my react app and came across react-to-print. However, I'd like to bypass the print options page and have my button automatically print the form. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Am also looking for the same solution.